# Refresh Visualforce Component inside Apex:Tab

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I have a problem with refreshing vf component after clicking on apex:tab
I tried rerender and some actionFunctions, but nothing works.

Here is code:

```
<apex:tab label="Overview" name="AccDetails" id="tabDetails" ontabenter="setActiveTabJS('AccDetails');">
<div class="left-column-75-new">
    <div class="column-item-25">
        <c:AccOverview id="c:AccOverview " accountID="{!accountID}"/>
    </div></apex:tab>
```

What i want is, that when i click from another tab on my tab Overview, it will rerender/refresh AccOverview component.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: I tried to add action function

```
<apex:actionFunction name="rerenderOverview" rerender="overviewPanel"/>
```

And wrap component into outputPanel

```
<apex:outputPanel id="overviewPanel">
                    <div class="column-item-25">
                        <c:AccountOverview id="AccountOverview" accountID="{!accountID}" />
                    </div>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
```

But its not working, still no refresh. I dont have any function in controler to do rerender

Comment: You have to use ontabenter attribute which calls an action funtion. In the action function you can use rerender attribute. 
 https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BHs0IAG

You can also find another answer, with the controller included here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AiH5IAK

Comment: David, have you tried adding the component apex:actionFunction and calling the controller's method from it to do the re-render?

Comment: I edited my question